# Incorrect sum when "+" to add 2 cell values

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a weird problem. When I try to add up two cell values using `=C79+C80`, I don't get the correct sum but with `=sum(C79:C80)`, the result is displayed correctly.

The cells `C79` and `C80`hold formulas themselves. `C79` holds `=100*C76/(100-C82)`  and `C80` holds `=100*C77/(100-C82)`

I tried using the "formula checker" and it weirdly shows during the "step-by-step" analysis the following just before I get the final result: **93375** + **93375**. When i go to the final step in the calculation the result is **93375** which is obviously incorrect. The only thing i noticed was that, right before the final result when it says **93375** + **93375** the second 93375 is displayed in italic: *93375*

Anyone got any ideas?

EDIT For clarification: If I overwrite the cell with the same formula `=C79+C80` the result is displayed correctly.

Comment: Welcome! To help you understand what's going on: please tell us also what is in cells C76, C77 and C82. Perhaps a small screenshot with a section of the sheet with these cells will also help.

Comment: It's very unusual,,, if possible please share the Workbook with us & will help to examine and fix the issue ☺

Comment: @JohnSUN Those are the Formulas and respective values: 
C76 = C75*C74*C71
C77 = C75*C74*C72
C82 = 20


C71 = 2.49
C72 = 2.49
C74 = 10,000
C75 = 3

Comment: @RajeshSinha Unfortunately that is not possible, due to confidentiality concerns.

Comment: @TrynRealHard ,, no issue and in this situation it would difficult to find the cause behind to fix it as I've written earlier what is happening is unusual behavior ☺

Comment: @TrynRealHard Some checking points I can think of - is there any circular reference? Is the workbook calculation set to automatic? Did you try pressing F9 to force Excel to do all recalculations?

Comment: @KennethL I did check this, yes - no circular reference, calculation was set to automatic. I also did try F9 for recalculation, no change. At this point I am inclined to consider this to be a weird bug and not an error on my end.

Comment: Didn't get any incorrect result based on your description, you should check if there are any TEXT format cells for calculation. https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7JdH.png Or you can upload the problem file or screenshot here.